# kendo grid filtering for email field

Tags: kendo-ui, filtering

I have developed a kendo UI grid in my HTML page and one of the columns is of type 'email'.
Now the problem is I cannot filter on the email type column data.

```
   model: {
   PrimaryEmail: { type: 'email' }
   }
```

To give more clarity, if I enter any text in the filter, it always takes Equal to condition, and the dropdown list is blank to select the condition.

Please let me know if we have a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the KendoUI [Model](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#modeldefine) does not support such data **type : "email**", so either you have to declare your field to type: "string" or it would take default as "string"

however if you need to validate column of the Grid as an e-mail you should enable it in the column validation options

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
           dataSource: {
               schema: {
                   model: {
                       id: "Id",
                       fields: {
                           Id: { editable: false },
                           PrimaryEmail: { type: "string", validation: { email: true, required: true} },
                           Username: { validation: { required: true} }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no type called email . The available options are **"string", "number", "boolean", "date"**. The default is "string" .

You may use the string for the Email Type then you will have all the conditions